# How to vuetify a dynamically generated vue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I recently created a plain table using the vuejs framework.  The result was a table with no functionality. My data is coming from a site that generated fake json data. Here's a working version in https://jsbin.com/retoqej/edit?html,css,output

```
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="user in users">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                users: []
            },
            created: function () {
                this.getListData();
            },
            methods: {
                getListData: function () {
                    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                    var vm = this;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: root + '/users',
                        method: 'GET'
                    }).then(function (data) {
                        vm.users = data;
                    });                                            

                },
                generateData: function (d) {
                    //this.data = d;
                    //alert("generateData");
                }
            }
        });     
    </script>


</body>
```

What I am trying to do next is to add functionality by making it sortable, searchable, etc.  After some research, I came across vuetify and tried to create a table similar to this example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables, but nothing happens.  I don't even get an error.  My JSON data is not hard-coded into the page like the example they have.  My JSON is coming from a site that generates fake json data.  Here's my codepen code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZzvax?editors=1010

**HTML**

```
    <div id="app">
            <template>
                <v-data-table
                    v-bind:headers="headers"
                    :items="items"
                    hide-actions
                    class="elevation-1"
                  >
                  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.username }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.email }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.phone }}</td>
                  </template>
                </v-data-table>
            </template>  

    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data () {
return {
  headers: [
    {
      text:'Name',
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      value:'name'
    },
    { text: 'First Name', value: 'username' },
    { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
    { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' }
  ],
  items: [],
  methods: {
                getListData: function () {
                    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                    var vm = this;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: root + '/users',
                        method: 'GET'
                    }).then(function (data) {
                        vm.items = data;
                    });                                            

                }
  }
}      
}
})
```

Comment: I was following the example from the vuetify site.  It appears to work but no data is being brought back.  There should be some data.

Comment: You're never calling `getListData`.

Comment: Here is your code fixed. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yvPmvj?editors=1010

Comment: Try not to use jQuery along with Vue. The default module for ajax calls on vue is axios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is you were never calling `getListData`. Once you do that, the AJAX call is made. Here is an updated version of your code.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created(){
    this.getListData()
  },
  methods: {
    getListData: function () {
      var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
      var vm = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: root + '/users',
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(function (data) {
        vm.items = data;
      });                                            

    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text:'Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value:'name'
        },
        { text: 'First Name', value: 'username' },
        { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
        { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' }
      ],
      items: []
    }
  }
})
```

Note the added `created` lifecycle handler that calls `getListData`. I also modified `getListData` to set `items`.

Here is your pen [updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yvPmvj?editors=1010).